Weird lines come in video feed from ZED2 camera
I am streaming the images from a ZED2 camera using a ROS2 humble topic on Jetson Orin NX JP 6.0
I get images like this from the left camera. Any idea why does it happen?
I drew the rectangles myself. But the issue is the those lines.
I tried the same camera with no setting change yesterday and it gave me clear images. I am not able to correlate what causes it to produce good/ bad images sometimes.
For your information, I am operating the camera in a glacier/ snowy environment. It was not sunny that day when I received the bad images, nor was it on the good image day. These lines remain consistent across different frames. Once in a while I get clear frame. ChatGPT says aliasing/ moire patterns.
I don't know much about tuning camera parameters but I have control over below ones.
video:
            brightness: 4 # [DYNAMIC] Not available for ZED X/ZED X Mini
            contrast: 4 # [DYNAMIC] Not available for ZED X/ZED X Mini
            hue: 0 # [DYNAMIC] Not available for ZED X/ZED X Mini
            saturation: 4 # [DYNAMIC]
            sharpness: 4 # [DYNAMIC]
            gamma: 8 # [DYNAMIC]
            auto_exposure_gain: true # [DYNAMIC]
            exposure: 80 # [DYNAMIC]
            gain: 80 # [DYNAMIC]
            auto_whitebalance: true # [DYNAMIC]
            whitebalance_temperature: 42 # [DYNAMIC] - [28,65] works only if `auto_whitebalance` is false

stream_server:
            stream_enabled: false # enable the streaming server when the camera is open
            codec: 'H264' # different encoding types for image streaming: 'H264', 'H265'
            port: 30000 # Port used for streaming. Port must be an even number. Any odd number will be rejected.
            bitrate: 12500 # [1000 - 60000] Streaming bitrate (in Kbits/s) used for streaming. See https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/api/structsl_1_1StreamingParameters.html#a873ba9440e3e9786eb1476a3bfa536d0
            gop_size: -1 # [max 256] The GOP size determines the maximum distance between IDR/I-frames. Very high GOP size will result in slightly more efficient compression, especially on static scenes. But latency will increase.
            adaptative_bitrate: false # Bitrate will be adjusted depending the number of packet dropped during streaming. If activated, the bitrate can vary between [bitrate/4, bitrate].
            chunk_size: 16084 # [1024 - 65000] Stream buffers are divided into X number of chunks where each chunk is chunk_size bytes long. You can lower chunk_size value if network generates a lot of packet lost: this will generates more chunk for a single image, but each chunk sent will be lighter to avoid inside-chunk corruption. Increasing this value can decrease latency.
            target_framerate: 0 # Framerate for the streaming output. This framerate must be below or equal to the camera framerate. Allowed framerates are 15, 30, 60 or 100 if possible. Any other values will be discarded and camera FPS will be taken.

Any help is highly appreciated to help understand and eliminate these lines!

